# UITableView cells customize problems with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell and one MutableArray with data, but when I set the cell text for one properties of my MutableArray, the application crash. Can you help me?

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//Cria identificador da célula
static NSString *cellID = @"dadosCell";

//Usa célula customizada da classe ProfissionalCell
ProfissionalCell *cell = (ProfissionalCell *) [self.dadosTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];


//Caso não tenha, aloca uma nova célula
if (cell == nil) {

    //Com StyleSubtitle, são mostrados título e descrição
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfissionalCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

}

//Profissional selecionado
NSInteger linha = indexPath.row;
Dados *parametro = [profissionais objectAtIndex:linha];

NSLog(@"Nome= %@", cell.cellNome.text);
NSLog(@"Parametro= %@",[[profissionais objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Nome"]);

//Preenche campos
cell.cellNome.text = parametro.nome;
cell.cellProfissao.text = parametro.profissao;
cell.cellEndereco.text = parametro.endereco;
cell.cellIndicacoes.text = parametro.indicacao;

return cell;
}
```

The crash is occurs in the line:

```
cell.cellNome.text = parametro.nome;
```

And the line returns "Parametro = null":

```
NSLog(@"Parametro= %@",[[profissionais objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Nome"]);
```

The object is OK, but I don't attribute a cell layer.

**EDITED**

If I replace the NSLog with code below:

```
NSLog(@"Nome= %@", [profissionais objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The results is:

```
Nome= {
"2013-12-08 19:35:43" = added;
Chibungo = Nome;
"" = Especialidade;
1 = id;
"Sao Paulo " = Cidade;
"11 9999-9999" = Telefone;
"teste@teste.com" = Email;
"Av. Paulista, 453" = Endereco;
"Servicos Gerais" = Profissao;
SP = Estado;}
```

How do attribute the key "Nome" only?

Comment: can you add the crash log?

Comment: What is the message in the crash log when the app crashes?

Comment: This is a log when app crashes:

Comment: 2013-12-12 22:05:37.799 Indiki[1756:70b] -[__NSDictionaryI nome]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a03570
2013-12-12 22:05:37.859 Indiki[1756:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI nome]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a03570'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0175c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014df8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x017f9903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSele...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help... I find the solutions for my questions.
The NSMutableArray was change inverse.. example: "Chibungo" is a Key and "Nome" is a value, but the correct was "Nome" is a key and "Chibungo" is a value.

And the code right is:

```
//Profissional da linha
NSInteger linha = indexPath.row;
NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary*)[profissionais objectAtIndex:linha];

//Preenche campos
cell.cellNome.text = [dic objectForKey: @"Nome"];
cell.cellProfissao.text = [dic objectForKey: @"Profissao"];
cell.cellEndereco.text = [dic objectForKey: @"Endereco"];
cell.cellIndicacoes.text = [dic objectForKey: @"Indicacoes"];

return cell;
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not initialized `mutableArray` Please check:-

```
NSMutableArray *profissionais=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: The class ".h" is initialized:  NSMutableArray *profissionais;  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *profissionais;

Answer (score 0):

You can check as follows to locate the problem:

1. make sure profissionais is not nil, and profissionais.count >= indexPath.row + 1
2. make sure [profissionais objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is a dictionary and it has the key @"Nome"

Comment: Yes, the "profissionais" is not nil, it's a 1 object. With 11 Keys:
[0] -> @"2013-12-08 19:35:43" : @"added"
[1] -> @"Chibungo" : @"Nome" 
[2] -> @"" : @"Especialidade" 
[3] -> (int)1 : @"id" 
[4] -> @"Sao Paulo " : @"Cidade" 
[5] -> @"11 9999-9999" : @"Telefone" 
[6] -> @"teste@teste.com" : @"Email" 
[7] -> @"1" : @"Indicacoes" 
[8] -> @"Av. Paulista, 453" : @"Endereco" 
[9] -> @"Servicos Gerais" : @"Profissao" 
[10] -> @"SP" : @"Estado"

Comment: In your project, what is the type of profissionais, it should be an array.

Comment: And from your crash log, it seems that profissionais contains dictionary, not Dados instance as you want, so the code "Dados *parametro = [profissionais objectAtIndex:linha];" will assign a dictionary to a Dados pointer. It surly will crash when you call parameter.nome.